# Mouse click causes blur event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, tapestry

I'm working on a Tapestry 5.3 webapp that uses jquery (jquery 1.10.2 and jquery-ui 1.10.3 via got5 tapestry-jquery).

Some of the autocomplete elements don't really work well: once I click a list item, it doesn't select anything. It only hides the options.

I expect a mouse click to select an item **and** hide the options. Now only the second thing occurs.

This is the call trace:

```
Tapestry.Initializer.autocomplete/options.close() JQueryAutocomplete.js:296
$.Widget.prototype._trigger() jquery-ui.js:785
._close() jquery-ui.js:7058
$.widget/</proxiedPrototype[prop]</<() jquery-ui.js:401
.close() jquery-ui.js:7050
$.widget/</proxiedPrototype[prop]</<() jquery-ui.js:401
._create/<.blur() jquery-ui.js:6786
handlerProxy() jquery-ui.js:701
jQuery.event.dispatch() jquery-1.10.2.js:5094
.onPriority/this._replaceDispatchMethod/$j.event.dispatch() POIJS.js:312
.onPriority/this._replaceDispatchMethod/$j.event.dispatch() POIJS.js:312
jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle() jquery-1.10.2.js:4766
jQuery.event.special.focus.trigger() jquery-1.10.2.js:5270
jQuery.event.trigger() jquery-1.10.2.js:4973
.trigger/<() jquery-1.10.2.js:5691
.each() jquery-1.10.2.js:657
jQuery.prototype.each() jquery-1.10.2.js:266
.trigger() jquery-1.10.2.js:5690
._create/<["click .ui-menu-item:has(a)"]() jquery-ui.js:11490
handlerProxy() jquery-ui.js:701
.onPriority/this._replaceDispatchMethod/$j.event.dispatch() POIJS.js:442
jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle()
```

Here is the related code excerpt:

```
;(function($j, undefined) {
  // some stuff skipped for the sake of brevity
  var goT5autocomplete = Tapestry.Initializer.autocomplete;

  Tapestry.Initializer.autocomplete = function(config) {
    // some stuff skipped for the sake of brevity
    var options = {
        select : function(event, ui) {
            console.log("select ..."); // I can **not** se this in the console log
            select = true; // already declared in the enclosing function
            if (!!ui.item.value) {
                element.val(ui.item.value);
            } else {
                element.val(ui.item.label);
            }
            clone.val(ui.item.label);
            clone.attr("data-value", element.val());
            element.trigger("autocompleteselect", ui);
            return false;
        },
        focus : function(event, ui) { // on dropdown menu element hover do not happen anything
            console.log("focus ...");  // I can **not** se this in the console log|
            return true;
        },
        search: function(e) {
            console.log("search ...");  // I can see this on the console log
            $j(this).data("CNGAutocomplete").menu.element.scrollTop(0);
            if (e.handleObj && e.handleObj.type === "input"){
                clone.removeAttr("data-value");
                element.val("");
            }
        },
        open: function() {
            console.log("open ..."); // I can see this on the console log
            $j(this).data("CNGAutocomplete").menu.element.scrollTop(0);
        },
        close: function(event, ui) {
            console.trace(); // this is how I obtain the call trace
            console.log("close... " + event + ", " + JSON.stringify(ui)); // I can see this on the console log
        }
    }
    if (config.options) {
        $j.extend(config.options, options);
    } else {
        config.options = options;
    }

    return goT5autocomplete(config);
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: can you show us some code ? How have you implemented the event-listener ?

Comment: So yes, according to the code excerpt above, there is an event listener for the 'select' event. Unfortunately, the usual mouse movements don't trigger this event. Instead, they are triggering the 'close' event that comes from a 'blur'.